# Translating terms like function and toggle

Tags: translation, input-methods

**Bolded terms** I'm struggling to translate using dictionaries and online resources:

1. My IME has a pronunciation lookup **function**.( <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> )

I've tried to find the right translation, but I'm not sure.

For instance:

我輸入法有一個搜尋發音**function**.

2. Some IMEs have a **toggle** . For instance: 倉/速 and 漢/汉 .

我輸入法有一個漢/汉**toggle**.

3. How does this sound?

I sometimes use zhuyin to **reinforce/emphasize** tones.

```
有時候我使用注音符號的輸入法為__b_聲調．
a. [學習]
b. [注重練習]
c. other?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. function 功能
2. toggle 切換
3. 有時候我使用注音符號的輸入法**来**_強化_聲調 or 有時候我**為了**_強化_聲調使用注音符號的輸入法

Comment: Thank you! Wow, that was fast too.